# Simple way to get test data into an App

Tags: android, iphone, ios

I need a simple way to get some test data (a single string value) into an iPhone / Android app.  We have currently been using S3 and Dropbox, however we need everyone (devs, testers, project managers) to ba able to access and change the test data.  We dont want to give out our S3 key and we cant get a shared public folder on Dropbox.

A colleague suggested using a shared google doc spreadsheet, which is an excellent idea, but I don't really want to prase all the [gumpf](http://code.google.com/apis/spreadsheets/data/3.0/developers_guide.html#CellFeeds) that comes with the response.  Is there a simpler solution?

Answer (score 2):

Couldn't you use a text file on your server?

Comment: yes and why not create a second app that allows users to change the test data.

Answer (score 1):

Webhotel with a json file which the app access.

Comment: It might not be free, but you can get really cheap webhotels solving your problem. But we'll I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could just store the data in the device's nsUserDefaults and allow users to change the string data in the settings app. Obviously it won't work across devices, but maybe you don't need that?